# Can't display image

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why doesn't display the avatar 100x100. Something is wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `verified` = 1 and         lastcheck=0 order by `authoredPostCount` DESC");
echo "<table border='1'> <tr>
<th>Picture</th>
<th>Verified</th>
<th>Videos</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row "<img src="['avatar']."></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['userId'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['authoredPostCount'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
if (!$cuserId) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: you storing image as name or as blob or how ?

Comment: show your sample data.

Comment: Did you solved already?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
echo "<td>" . $row "<img src="['avatar']."></td>";
```

With

```
echo "<td><img src=". $row['avatar']."></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are saving image file name in database then use it like that

```
     echo "<td><img src='path/to/folder/". $row['avatar'].".jpeg'></td>";
```